# No shower water until sink turned on!

Tags: plumbing

Last week plumber installed new vanity faucet, supply lines in small hall bath.  Now the shower in that bathroom and the one in master bath do not have water until the sink is turned on...when sink is turned off the showers go off and there is no hot water...HELP!!

Answer (score 0):

## You need to call back the plumber.

Comment: Call into them now- but already know it's not going to be "related" to previous problem - is it ever??LOL Never heard of a problem like this before - thats why I was hoping someone else had a clue.  but thanks